# How can I debug NPE in Grails?

Tags: grails, groovy

I try to execute raw SQL in Grails with this code:

```
class PlainSqlService {

    def dataSource // the Spring-Bean "dataSource" is auto-injected

    def newNum = {
        def sql = new Sql(dataSource) // Create a new instance of groovy.sql.Sql with the DB of the Grails app
        def q = "SELECT a.xaction_id, a.xdin FROM actions a WHERE a.is_approved = 0"
        def result = sql.rows(q) // Perform the query
                return result
    }
}
```

But I get this exception at runtime.
**sql object is not null!**

How can I debug it?

```
2011-02-13 15:55:27,507 [http-8080-1] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - Exception occurred when processing request: [GET] /moderator/login/index
Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at moderator.PlainSqlService$_closure1.doCall(PlainSqlService.groovy:17)
    at moderator.PlainSqlService$_closure1.doCall(PlainSqlService.groovy)
    at moderator.LoginController$_closure1.doCall(LoginController.groovy:29)
    at moderator.LoginController$_closure1.doCall(LoginController.groovy)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: you have to paste in the source in its entirety if you want any help from debugging using a stacktrace. Otherwise, those line numbers mean nothing - unless you expect psychic debugging from us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell what's going on from the limited code you're providing, but there are some things to check. Is the service injected into the controller with a class-scope field "def plainSqlService" like you have here for the dataSource, or are you calling `new PlainSqlService()`? If you're creating a new instance then the dataSource bean won't be injected and the groovy.sql.Sql constructor won't fail, but queries will.

One thing to try is `grails clean` - whenever something like this that should work doesn't, a full recompile often helps.

One important but unrelated point - you should never use Closures in services. Controllers and taglibs require that actions and tags be implemented with a Closure, but a Service is just a Spring bean defined in Groovy. Spring knows nothing about Closures and since they're just a field that Groovy executes as if it were a method, any proxying that you're expecting from Spring (in particular transactional behavior, but also security and other features) will not happen since Spring only looks for methods.

So `newNum` should be declared as:

```
def newNum() {
   ...
}
```